# Delete columns if condition is matched in all but one cell in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix `A` of size 13472x30974. In the first row, there is always a value (from 1 to 30974). I would like to delete the columns, if all other values in the specific column are `NaN`.

I can delete the columns, if I separate the first row from the rest of the matrix, yet I won't be able to combine the two matrices then (because they will be of different size).

```
B = A(:, ~all(isnan(A)));
```

I guess that using `any` instead of `all` won't return the desired output neither, as some columns might contain values with `NaN` and real values.

So how could I address the part of the matrix from `2:13472`, yet delete from `1:13472`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `isnan` on the `2:end` rows

```
B = A( :, ~all(isnan(A(2:end, :))) )
```

- Runs the `isnan` on `A` excluding the first row - `A(2:end, :)`
- Outputs all rows of `A` - `A(:, ___ )`

---

If you just want to *remove* the matching columns, instead of assigning to `B` then use

```
A( :, all(isnan(A(2:end, :))) ) = [];
```